# percent capture value using if-else list condition

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

For the sorted list `l = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]`

A 75% "threshold" is defined as `pct_value = 0.75*sum(l)`

I want to find the value at which the threshold is reached. In this given list, since `cumsum(l) = array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  9, 11, 14])`, the threshond `pct_value` is crossed at the value `l[-2]`. I want to write a program that finds this value at which the threshold is reached.

My if-else condition isn't correct:

`pct_value = 10.5`

`[i+i if i+i < pct_value else i for i in L]`

Any suggestion would be appreciative to fix the condition.

Comment: can u give some exampe inputs and expected output

Comment: `i+i if i+i < pct_value else i+i` this is the same as `i+i`. You have the same expression for both the `if` and the `else` part...

Comment: @Bakuriu: Edited if-else condition but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар: I have a text file that I can share. Let me come up with a small set of data as an example.

Comment: If you can use NumPy: `a[np.diff(np.cumsum(a) >= np.sum(a) * 0.75)]` (`a` is the input `np.array`). This returns a one-element array with the number you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is this what you want?

```
def find_element(L):
    pct = 0.75 * sum(L)
    s = 0
    for i, element in enumerate(L):
        if s > pct:
            break
        else:
            s += element
    return L[i]
```

Comment: Couple of things: `sum` is a python function so can't be used as variable and second It probably is giving index of where threshold is reached not value at that point

Comment: `pct` has to be recalculated every iteration, if I understood his problem right. e.g something like `pct = 0.75 * sum(s)` at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: @data I don't think so

Comment: @laike9m: Thanks. Please put colons along your if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to remove the trailing elements from a copy until you hit your target. This returns a copy of the list elements that satisfy the stated condition:

```
li=[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  9, 11, 14]

li_c=li[:]
while sum(li_c)>=sum(li)*.75:
    li_c.pop()

print li_c    
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

To make that more efficient, you would use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

li_c=deque(li)
tgt=sum(li)*.75

while sum(li_c)>=tgt:
    li_c.pop()

print li_c    
# deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9])
```

If you are just looking for the index, not a copy of the elements, you can also use a while loop to do that:

```
i=1
while i<len(li):
    if sum(li[0:i+1])>=tgt:
        break
    else:
        i+=1    

print i, li[0:i], i-len(li)  
# 7 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9] -2
```